# Issue Stopping CSS Animation on Final Image

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm working on a CSS transition script for virtual graduation. I'm trying to get an animation to land on the final slide but it keeps flipping back to the first slide once complete. I don't know how to stop the final transition on the completed image. If anyone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong it would be a huge help.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;   
}
li {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top:0;
}
img{
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  animation: xfade 16s 0s 1;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  animation: xfade 16s 4s 1;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  animation: xfade 16s 8s 1;
}
li:nth-child(1) {
  animation: xfade 16s 12s 1;
}
@keyframes xfade{
  17% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  92% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img title="" alt="" src="https://www.harpercollege.edu/dev/homepage/images/home-slide-4.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img title="" alt="" src="https://www.harpercollege.edu/dev/homepage/images/home-slide-3.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img title="" alt="" src="https://www.harpercollege.edu/dev/homepage/images/home-slide-2.jpg" /></li>    
  <li><img title="" alt="" src="https://www.harpercollege.edu/dev/homepage/images/home-slide-1.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: animation-fill-mode: forwards;

Comment: Since animation is a loop

Start with the end image first but don't show it make it opacity to 0, you only want to show it after the circle completed.

since you only got 4 children you can time the ending animation with the animation delay.

Answer (score 0):

First, add `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to stop the animation going back to the start state after it finish.

Then, it would be better to add the **0% and 100% selector** inside **@keyframes**. If this selector is missing, the animation maybe problematic.

```
@keyframes xfade{
  0%, 17% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  92%, 100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```